# unix - awk - print argument name in user-defined function

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

Say with the below awk inside a bash script:

How can you get the print_line function to print the name of the argument passed in?
ie this output

```
array passed in was:
arrayprime
array passed in was:
arraymagic
```

Just a snippet of the gist of the code (not whole thing):

```
awk -F"$delim" '
NR>1 { 

        print_line(arrayprime)
        print_line(arraymagic)
}
    func print_line(arr)
    {
        print "array passed in was:"
            print arr
    }

} ' "$filename"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `awk` does not have the ability to be this introspective.

The `C` language can do this through the use of the C preprocessor.  If you really want to roll this type of behavior into your awk function, then you could look into use the C preprocessor or perhaps write a [GNU M4 macro](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/)

If you're willing to add just one more parameter, you could do.

```
awk -F"$delim" '
NR>1 { 

        print_line(arrayprime, "arrayprime")
        print_line(arraymagic, "arraymagic")
}
    func print_line(arr, name)
    {
        print "array passed in was:"
            print name
    }

}' "$filename"
```

Comment: Like most languages, ask uses http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value, not http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_name.